# How to easily create webapps for websites and the deploy them into the snap store for ubuntu?

Tags: snap, webapps, desktop-apps

I would like to do this **easily** to someone's website and deploy the app for websites with javascript, CSS, HTML like fallingrain.com **for ubuntu**. Could someone help me?

I think there might be some way to do this with [chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions), could you clarify?

Comment: What kind of app(s) do you wish to create for a website?  A specific example may help other users to provide appropriate solutions.

Comment: Google Chrome and Chromium both have `--app` flag, where you have `google-chrome --app='http://foo.com'` opening foo.com in webapp mode. But that makes either of the websites a dependency, and it's not guaranteed user has them installed. So ideally if you're making a web app, make a small user interface for it, perhaps a very minimal web browser implemented in Python or Perl would do the trick. But as far as snaps go, I can't suggest much

Comment: The best place to ask this question is our sibling site specializing in snap packaging support: http://snapcraft.io. Your definition of "easy" may differ from other folks', so consider including a simple definition of "easy"

Comment: Chrome os has a structure of web apps. I would like to make some for Ubuntu.

Comment: user535733, I am referring to something simple that does not require another programing language or things that one has to get out of his/her way for.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in the Contributor License Agreement that explicitly prohibits this so long as:

1. You have signed the agreement, and
2. The code is published and licensed appropriately

However, in addition to the criteria, there is some leeway for subjective assessment.  If I were a moderator for the snap repository, I'd be questioning this under the concept of it being a useful tool vs "marketing" for the website.

In my opinion, for example, if you wrapped something like draw.io into a webapp snap, then it would probably be approved, but if you wrapped mysupermarketwebsite.com it probably wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you! The website that I want to do first is for a friend.

Comment: He will allow me If I contact him.